# subject line of email message

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, email

I'm writing an asp.net mvc app. in c#, and I'm wondering if anybody can help me to understand, if it's possible to include an input from another field stored in the database, like a numeric or text string into a subject line of the email.

For example, along with the subject text, like "Your event registration" I'd like to add a "registartion ID" into a subject line of my email.

Right now i have a code in my emailhepler.cs:

```
public static void NotifyHtml(string toAddress, string subject, string body)
    {
        MailMessage message = new MailMessage();

        message.To.Add(toAddress);
        message.From = new MailAddress("coe-RoomReservations@coe.berkeley.edu");
        message.Subject = subject;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. When you call your method, you should be able to format your subject however you want. E.g.,

```
NotifyHtml("coe-RoomReservations@coe.berkeley.edu", string.format("#{0} Your event registration", registrationId), body);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
message.Subject = String.Format("{0} : {1}", subject, registrationID);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Hope I didn't misunderstand your question. `MailMessage.Subject` is just a property of type String so you can include anything that's formatted as a string.

```
message.Subject = string.Format("Your event registration; registration id : {0}", registrationId);
```